# how to use Service

Tags: android

I need a service that run at different process and start at boot .

Also My Application should communicate with that ,

Also I do not want allow other appliaction to use my service .

is there any way ?

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        service = ((BoxService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        service = null;
    }
};

void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, BoxService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

This works well when I use service at my process  , but when I want to use that at diffrent process , I get error in binding ,

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

See this link

```
AddFenceActivity.this.startService(new Intent(
                    AddFenceActivity.this, Location_Services.class));
```